# C# reliable way to pattern match?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

At the moment I am trying to match patterns such as

`text text date1 date2`

So I have regular expressions that do just that. However, the issue is for example if users input data with say more than 1 whitespace or if they put some of the text in a new line etc the pattern does not get picked up because it doesn't **exactly** match the pattern set.

Is there a more reliable way for pattern matching? The goal is to make it very simple for the user to write but make it easily matchable on my end. I was considering stripping out all the whitespace/newlines etc and then trying to match the pattern with no spaces i.e. `texttextdate1date2`.

Anyone got any better solutions?

**Update**

Here is a small example of the pattern I would need to match:

`FIND me@test.com 01/01/2010 to 10/01/2010`

Here is my current regex:

`FIND [A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4} [0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4} to [0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{2,4}`

This works fine 90% of the time, however, if users submit this information via email it can have all different kinds of formatting and HTML I am not interested in. I am using a combination of the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) and a HTML tag removing regex to strip all the HTML from the email, but even at that I can't seem to get a match on some occassions.

I believe this could be a more parsing related question than pattern matching, but I think maybe there is a better way of doing this...

Comment: There's absolutely no problem to match multiple whitespaces with a regexp. Show us the pattern and you will get at new one in return. :)

Comment: @Jonas, the regex does actually match the whitespace well I already have one that solves the problem. My issue is I am coming across situations where sometimes the information is on separate lines etc or perhaps by mistake the user has entered a couple of extra unwanted whitespaces between text. I want to be able to handle these situations.

Comment: @James, please post the regular expression that you are using.

Comment: A proper regex query can handle those situations easily

Comment: @James if you want to match an e-mail address your regex should support the standards (http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) - there's an example here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: Please note that the "[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}" part of your regex will not match the following e-mail address: someone@example.travel, which is perfectly valid, but will match "-1@...com, which is not.

Comment: @Igor it is highly unlikely we will support emails in such a format, the email regex seems to work fine at the moment and is actually matched against a database anyway so no spoof emails can be sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match at least one or more whitespace characters (space, tab, newline), use:

```
\s+
```

Substitute the above wherever you have the physical space in your pattern and you should be fine.

Comment: I think this might be all I am missing actually. I will adapt my regex and see if it works!

Comment: Is there way to determine and detect which type of whitespace you have found?

Answer (score 2):

Example of matching multiple groups in a text with multiple whitespaces and/or newlines.

```
var txt = "text text   date1\ndate2";
var matches = Regex.Match(txt, @"([a-z]+)\s+([a-z]+)\s+([a-z0-9]+)\s+([a-z0-9]+)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

matches.Groups[n].Value with n from 1 to 4 will contain your matches.

Answer (score 0):

I would split the string into a string array and match each resulting string to the necessary Regular Expression.

Answer (score 0):

```
\b(text)[\s]+(text)[\s]+(date1)[\s]+(date2)\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a nasty expression but here is something that will work for the input you provided:

> `^(\w+)\s+([\w@.]+)\s+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})[^\d]+(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})$`

This will work with variable amounts of whitespace between the capture groups as well.

Comment: Incorrect I'm afraid, `\w` and `@` as well as any whitespace character (except `\n`) and the subsequent digits will be matched by `.`, basically greedy matching. Use the `?` suffix for non-greedy matching.

Comment: The `.` is a member of the character class so it does not represent a metacharacter, rather the literal value `"."`

Answer (score 0):

Through ORegex you can tokenize your string and just pattern match on token sequences:

```
var tokens = input.Split(new[]{' ','\t','\n','\r'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var oregex = new ORegex<string>("{0}{0}{1}{1}", IsText, IsDate);

var matches = oregex.Matches(tokens); //here is your subsequence tokens.

...

public bool IsText(string str)
{
    ...
}

public bool IsDate(string str)
{
    ...
}
```